# Automatic Ubuntu server installation not working - error with booting from usb drive

Tags: 14.04, boot, server, mount

I am working on automatic Ubuntu installation iso file. I followed the guide shown here: https://pricklytech.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/ubuntu-server-unattended-installation-custom-cd/

The iso file itself works (from USB), but not automatically, because I get this error:

```
Your installation CD-ROM couldn't be mounted. This probably means
that yhe CD-ROM was not in the drive. If so you can insert it and try 
again. 

Retry mounting the CD-ROM? 
<YES>                          <NO>
```

So to fix this, I would need to open another terminal using: Alt + f2. 
Now if I write df -h, I get this following results:

```
none  382.6M    100.0K    382.4M    0%   /run
devtmpfs   1.9M    0      1.9G      0%   /dev
/dev/sdb1  29.0G   1.6G   27.4G     6%   /media
```

Now I just have to run 2 commands, to get everything working:

```
umount /dev/sdb1
mount /dev/sdb1 /cdrom
```

Now if I go back to the question: Retry mounting the CD-ROM? and answer YES, 
Everything runs smoothly and it install my ubuntu server 14.04 flawlessly.

Question: I really need to make it unattended, is there a workaround here so I don't have to umount and mount again? Should I just give static IP-addresses and use boot over network instead?

This is not a virtual machine, in VM it works fine without problems. 
I have motherboard with APU and 1 wiped harddrive using GParted quick erase. I do not have CD-rom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your ISO into a hybrid ISO, so the installation will see your usb as a hdd/cd-rom.

```
$ apt-get install syslinux
$ isohybrid path/to/image.iso

$ lsblk
sde                                     8:64   1   7.4G  0 disk  
└─sde1                                  8:65   1   7.4G  0 part  /media/usbdrive
```

If it's been automounted, as is the case above, unmount it first:

```
$ umount /media/usbdrive
```

Use dd to write the ISO image to the disk path. That's /dev/sde NOT /dev/sde1:

```
$ dd if=path/to/image.iso of=/dev/sde
```

Source: https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/iso2usb

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please edit your answer to include the basic steps for such a procedure. This way, if the link becomes unavailable for some reason, your answer will remain helpful and relevant.